# No bass from my laptop's build in subwoofer on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS on my laptop, running alongside Windows 10 on UEFI, but I run into a few problems. Most of them are fixed now but one thing that bothers me is the fact that I get no bass whenever I playback music through my build-in JBL speakers.

I know that it's a known issue but I would really appreciate if someone could answer me in simple words what I should do to fix this problem.
Although I've been using Ubuntu for years I never took the chance to BE an real Ubuntu user, so yeah, I'd appreciate a simple, step by step, solution for this problem. Though I have a small suspicion that Ubuntu might not "see" my Reaktek sound card at all. I run `sudo aplay -l` and I got the results below

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3239 Analog [ALC3239 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC3239 Digital [ALC3239 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

As you can see my Realtek soundcard is not present at all. But honestly, I have little to none experience using terminal thus I'm asking your help here.

Thank you in advance and I hope that I'll get better in the future to contribute myself in this community, as well.

Comment: card1 is your realtek sound card. card0 is the HDMI audio out.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, cause I had got a little confused!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your sound settings in the System Settings app.

In the sound section you will have a list of sound cards , you might need to experiment with the Mode dropdown list to find the right mode to drive your speakers.

if they run from a single mini jack/headphone socket then use Analogue Stereo

if they run from multiple jack outputs or optical or spdif then chose the a surround mode.

If this doesn't fix it for you then its possible that the mapping of the various outputs (left,right,sub) is not correct for the ports you have.

As this is a laptop i would expect it to only have a single jack socket.

If the speakers are built into to the monitor then you should just need to configure the correct mode in Sound settings.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear enough. The subwoofer is located ON my laptop, on the bottom of it. The speakers are in the standard position though, below the screen.

The sound is fine when I output sound through the audio jack though. The bass lacks only when I playback music from the build in speakers.

Comment: And I forgot to mention  that the drop down menu gives me only one option, "Analog Stereo Output". And the available sound cards are just the main one (the one that I'm using right now - no bass) and the digital output S/PDIF, which is just an audio jack next to the main audio jack of my laptop (Lenovo Y50-70), pretty useless. So what am I doing now?

Comment: try jack_hda_retask

Comment: tried it but I don't actually know what to do there...

Comment: you can use jack_hda_retask to change the assigment of audio inputs and outputs to different connectors on your laptop. In your case it looks like you need to do enable 2.1 output instead of stereo output or provide power via some i2c command to wake up the crossover circuit that your laptop uses to spilt the audio signal between its speakers and sub.